# Two sample multivariate t-test?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, two-sample

I am wondering if there is a relatively easy way to implement a multivariate t-test or something analogous in R. I am aware of Hotelling's T-squared test, but in my case p>n and I've read that this test is not appropriate for singular matrices. 
If anyone can recommend an alternative test, or a way to normalize the data (perhaps X^T*X?) it would be greatly appreciated .

Thanks